# Which tennis matches are best of 5?

Tags: tennis

I am researching statistical characteristics of tennis matches. I need to know reliably which tennis matches are best of 3, and which ones are best of 5.

Is it strictly the case that only men grand slams are best of 5? Are the venues for the grand slams only used for grand slams (e.g. if I see that the venue of a tennis match is Wimbledon, am I guaranteed that this is the Wimbledon Grand slam)? Or are there sometimes some matches in these venues that are not part of the Grand slams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grand Slam mens singles and doubles are best of five sets.  The same is true of the Davis Cup.  However all other matches, male and female, and including the end of season ATP World Tour Finals, are best of three sets.

With regards the venues, I know that they can be used for Davis Cup as well as the Grand Slam, but as this just means the same number of sets, for your requirements, this is not a problem.

Comment: But last Olympics was played at Wimbledon & it was a best of 3 set matches

Comment: All matches at the last olympics where best of 3 except the final see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics#Format)

Answer (score 1):

All ATP tournamnet matches (singles/doubles) are best of three except for Grand Slam singles, that are best of five, Wimbledon doubles (best of five) and Olympics (best of five).

The only Grand Slam with doubles played best of five sets is Wimbledon.

The venues are used for Davis Cup matches.